# Problem in deploying node js app to plesk server

Tags: node.js, deployment

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

```
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1001
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

You may get additional information about this error condition by logging stdout and stderr of the node.exe process. To enable logging, set the system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled configuration setting to 'true' (current value is 'false').
```

**Above is the error I am getting**

I installed node js application on plesk and followed the instructions but it showing me the error please help